# How to use a database in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, database-connection

I'm a novice programmer, and I'm working with somebody to create a simple application in Visual Studio 2017 Community that uses a local embedded database for storing data. We've been having a lot of trouble getting a database to work, so I wanted to ask a few questions so that we could stop spinning our wheels.

1. What's the specific type of database that Visual Studio uses by default? I assume it's some form of SQL, but am unsure of what. Specifically, does the default type support Upsert?
2. What is the exact process for connecting a database to a DataGridView so that it can be queried and its table data viewed? I've tried cobbling this information together from various tutorials on the internet, but to no success, and Microsoft's documentation is pretty terrible in this regard.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a moment to read [How To Ask A Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read over the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You can also see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) which is a general overview of localDB for visual studio.

Comment: [Here is an example of a windows app with a local embedded database](https://github.com/crowcoder/CSharpCrudGrid). It uses Sqlite which is very common for embedding a database with your app. The example is winforms which is not considered very modern but it may have value as reference.

Comment: To answer part 1, there is no standard database for visual studio. You can code to whatever database you need, depending on requirements. Sqlite is one of many, and you should find many tutorials on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

First, as usual, we use sqlserver localdb in visual studio. Of course, it supports Upsert.

Second, you can try the following code to connect database and select data from the table.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionstring = @"connectionstring";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "select * from Student";
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);
            connection.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]